# Unable to switch to iframe using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, iframe, drag-and-drop

I am trying to learn the feature drag and drop in the webpage
[Link](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/)
The Section Books is inside the iframe.
But i am unable to access the iframe I am getting below error

> no such element: Unable to locate element:

Below are the Xpath i tried

```
// WebElement frame =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='root']//iframe[@class='st-preview-body']"));
// WebElement frame =driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
   WebElement frame =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='https://snippet.webixcode.com/snippet.html?0.0.3']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```

I also tried using by.id and also xpath using id and class name

What will be the mistake i am doing? To my knowledge there is only one iframe present

The code for drag and drop. will this work?

```
WebElement fromdrag=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='dhx_tree-list-item__text'][normalize-space()='Lawrence Block']"));
WebElement todrop=driver.findElement(By.id("treeTarget"));
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
act.dragAndDrop(fromdrag, todrop).build().perform();
```

Comment: HI @pamdhu Thanks for ur comment . i have entered into frames next is i want to do drag and drop ,Below is my piece of code  '''''  WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='dhx_tree-list__item dhx_tree-list-item']//span[@class='dhx_tree-list-item__text'][normalize-space()='Lawrence Block']"));
    
         System.out.println(ele1.getText());
 
 Actions act=new Actions(driver);
   act.dragAndDropBy(ele1, 448,37).build().perform(); Am getting NowindowException .Couldnt proceed further the drag and drop .

Comment: That action worked fine, without any errors for me. Refer this link - [darganddrop](https://www.guru99.com/drag-drop-selenium.html). And check the `Note` `The pixels values change with screen resolution and browser size. This method is hence not reliable and not widely used.`

Answer (score 0):

Its a `Nested iframe`. We need to switch to those `iframes` one by one to access `Elements` from `All Books`.

The page takes time to load, better apply `Explicit waits` to find the Elements. And you also need to `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` to come out of the iframe and find `Elements` outside the `iframe`

```
public void iframequestion() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\expediaproject\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        
        driver.get("https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/");
        
        WebElement frame1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/3e0b5r57?mode=mobile']"));
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", frame1);
        driver.switchTo().frame(frame1);
        
        WebElement frame2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='st-preview-body']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(frame2);
        
        WebElement frame3 = driver.findElement(By.id("content"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(frame3);
        
        WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Fiction & Fantasy']"));
        System.out.println(ele1.getText());
        
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        
        WebElement ele2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='View more demos']"));
        System.out.println(ele2.getText());
        driver.quit();
    }
```

```
Fiction & Fantasy
View more demos
```

Comment: HI @pamdhu Thanks for ur comment . i have entered into frames next is i want to do drag and drop ,